# error shows while moving file to date folder on google Drive

Tags: vba

The below mentioned VBA code works perfectly when i run it on Local Hard disk however when i run and move files saved on google drive and if number of files are more than 50 it shows runtime error (only on Google Drive) can someone help.

Run-time Error 75:

Path/file Access error

Below mentioned is the code

```
Sub moveAllFilesInDateFolder()
 Dim DateFold As String, fileName As String
 Const sFolderPath As String = "G:\My Drive\Source"
 Const dFolderPath As String = "G:\My Drive\Destination\07102022"
 
 DateFold = dFolderPath & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") ' create the folder if it does not exist
 If Dir(DateFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir DateFold
 
 fileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.*")

 Do While fileName <> ""
    Name sFolderPath & "\" & fileName As DateFold & "\" & fileName
    fileName = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```